# Button shifts location when changing content of react component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Here is the issue demonstrated in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ux0jzcxt/2/).
[image: Demonstration of issue in jsfiddle]

I have sections that change content when a button is clicked. I want the button to stay in place so that the user can just keep on clicking in the same place to change the content. I could just change the body height to some arbitrary large number and there would not be an issue, but I have no way of knowing what the highest possible height would be, nor do I want wasted space.

The HTML:

```
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration.js">
</script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
class Modules extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    let sections = [];

    let firstSection = [
        { title: "section 1, page 1", body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin risus massa, gravida id mattis quis, pellentesque at ante. Mauris pellentesque, ligula laoreet lacinia interdum, orci dolor bibendum elit, et fringilla magna orci sit amet ipsum. Vivamus vel lacus tristique, blandit lectus vel, lobortis odio." },
        { title: "section 1, page 2", body: "In tincidunt, erat eget venenatis interdum, neque dolor lobortis neque, vel mollis purus lacus ut orci. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras non dictum risus. Ut id augue in ex sollicitudin blandit vitae quis libero. Quisque hendrerit imperdiet imperdiet. Curabitur pretium nulla in augue feugiat sagittis. Vestibulum lacinia, ex ac luctus bibendum, dolor eros finibus elit, sed finibus massa orci eget tortor." },
        { title: "section 1, page 3", body: "Integer dapibus nibh in ex pellentesque condimentum. Aliquam erat urna, imperdiet at nunc ut, dictum convallis nunc. Sed pretium nunc eu augue eleifend gravida. Nulla ligula metus, vehicula ut fermentum vitae, accumsan vel odio. Vestibulum rhoncus pharetra nisl, eget volutpat nibh." }
    ];

    let secondSection = [
        { title: "section 2, page 1", body: "Curabitur pretium nulla in augue feugiat sagittis. Vestibulum lacinia, ex ac luctus bibendum, dolor eros finibus elit, sed finibus massa orci eget tortor. In placerat justo et dolor lobortis, laoreet molestie diam commodo. Pellentesque sit amet justo turpis. Morbi nulla nibh, luctus quis elit sit amet, convallis facilisis erat. Sed at malesuada justo. Fusce consectetur ornare urna, nec varius est. Aliquam dictum eros iaculis ex egestas auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit." },
        { title: "section 2, page 2", body: "Vivamus vel lacus tristique, blandit lectus vel, lobortis odio." },
        { title: "section 2, page 3", body: "Nulla ligula metus, vehicula ut fermentum vitae, accumsan vel odio. Vestibulum rhoncus pharetra nisl, eget volutpat nibh." }
    ];

    //add each section
    sections.push(firstSection);
    sections.push(secondSection);


    this.state = {
        currentPage: sections.map(section => 0),
        sections: sections
    };
}

changeToSectionToRight(index) {
    if(this.state.currentPage[index] < this.state.sections[index].length - 1)                 
    {
      this.state.currentPage[index]++;
      this.setState(this.state);
    }
}

changeToSectionToLeft(index) {
    if(this.state.currentPage[index] > 0) {
      this.state.currentPage[index]--;
      this.setState(this.state);
    }
}

render() {
    let sectionsArray = this.state.sections.map((content, index) => {
        return <div className="default-label">
                    <button onClick={this.changeToSectionToLeft.bind(this, index)}>&larr;</button>
                    <div className="module-body">
                        <p><b>{content[this.state.currentPage[index]].title}</b></p>                                    {content[this.state.currentPage[index]].body}
                    </div>
                    <button onClick={this.changeToSectionToRight.bind(this, index)}>&rarr;</button>
             </div>
    });

    return <div>
        {sectionsArray}
     </div>;
  }
}

React.render( <Modules/> , document.getElementById('container'));
```

The CSS:

```
body {
/*setting to tall enough height 'fixes' the issue*/
  /*height: 2400px;*/
}

.default-label {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 250px;
}

.module-body {
  padding: 10px;
}

button {
  height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: have you tried putting a `max-width` on `.module-body` to keep it from encroaching on the button? if i am interpreting this correctly...also just an idea not sure if its what you want

Comment: You could save the height of the bottom div (using a ref). Then each time you change the content, set the height of the bottom div to the max of the current height and the previously saved height

Comment: i misunderstood what you wanted ill keep thinking

Comment: i think you have to subtract the height of the short div on the bottom after clicking, from the long div that the short div replaces...and add that much extra space to the bottom under the lower div with javascript somehow

Comment: @klugjo Having a fixed height seems like it would be an issue because the width of the modules should be dynamic based on the screen resolution. When the width adjusts, the height would need to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can achieve what you want if you if you give a specific height to the module body and then just set the content to the height you want for example 200px and then give the box that is holding the text an overflow-x: scroll; property.

Comment: I don't think this produces the desired effect of modules having dynamic sizes. I don't want scroll bars on the modules. Also, although I do not show it in my jsfiddle (to keep the code simple) clicking to the next page might reveal or remove modules below (in my actual application). So a fixed height would not fix that because you could have say, eight modules and then clicking the next page would only leave two modules.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I could come up with is adding a margin at the bottom of the div containing all the modules. This way, there will always be a buffer which will help prevent a situation where the scroll bar is close to the bottom. Here's an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ux0jzcxt/5/).

```
.module-container {
  margin-bottom: 600px;
}
```

That being said, it's not perfect because you have space allocated that you do not need and it doesn't prevent the situation when there is a really high vertical resolution. Perhaps, if you know the resolution, there is a way to calculate the exact margin-bottom that will prevent this situation, but I do not know what the math would be.

[image]